# A check before saving to the Cloud Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, cloud

I want to do a check on the cloud first before I save the data. For example...

Do a query to check if a Task name and User situated to it is there.
If there is update it.
If not save to the cloud.

I'm having the issue with checking with two params like you could with SQLite on Android.

Any Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `whereEqualTo` multiple times to add more constraints to the query.

Comment: Hi nasch! I managed to get it to work with that so thank you! Was reading the documentation and they didn't explain using more then one so was a bit confused. Thank you though!